Custom cache key name in nuxt3 + nitro
When using swr cache routing in the default server nitro in nuxt3, how to specify the name of the generated cache key?
This is my nitro configuration
nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr: true,

    nitro: {
        routeRules: {
            '/': {
                swr: 7200,
            },
        },
        storage: {
            cache: {
                driver: 'redis',
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 6379,
                db: 0,
            },
        },
        devStorage: {
            cache: {
                driver: 'redis',
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 6379,
                db: 0,
            },
        },
        externals: {
            traceInclude: [],
        },
    },
})


I get redis data with key name nitro:routes:_:index.il7asoJjJE.jsonredis db
I have visited several related question links, but there are no answers that I thought of
https://github.com/unjs/nitro/discussions/1170
https://github.com/unjs/nitro/issues/1660
nitro doc cache
